# Internet not working in my Dell Inspiron-5520

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, dell

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my Dell Inspiron-5520 laptop. Though everything else seems to work properly the wireless network doesn't seem to work which worked perfectly when I had Windows 7 installed. I also tried connecting to internet using a wired network and that too doesn't work. Please help me as I am new at this. I might be wrong but I think there might be a problem with my network drivers. In any case my laptop uses BCM43142 chipset.

Comment: Pls post  the output of `lspci` and `ifconfig`.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
<http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385>

Comment: @WildMan I have done as you said. Here is the link to the contents of wireless-info file. http://pastebin.com/SK0y0t4V

Comment: Please run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` and then output of `ifconfig` also try `rfkill list wlan` to check if it's not blocked by any hardware switch

Comment: @kubahaha The 'sudo ifconfig wlan0' up command gives output as 'wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device'

Comment: @quruprasad check out the link. The output for lspci and ifconfig is there. pastebin.com/chtvV4QW

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you upgrade to 13.10 it supports your wireless card by default, then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

wireless should come on, if it does not please post the wireless info again from the script so we can see the current state of your wireless.

Comment: Here is the link to what I get in the terminal when I execute the above commands. http://pastebin.com/EeUZRJ7D and here is the link for wireless-info http://pastebin.com/cjGd7Za4

Comment: I edited the first line of code please try again. Thanks

Comment: Here is the output from the terminal. Please check it out  http://pastebin.com/EkTXkb9A

Comment: Where did you install this kernel from? link please.

Comment: By kernel if you mean Ubuntu 12.04 then here is the link from where I downloaded it http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. If you mean something else then I didnt install anything else other than the OS. Sorry if I cant be of much help, I really dont know as I am new here.

Comment: Is this a new install? have you ran all updates yet?

Comment: No its a new install. I just installed today. The wireless network should have been detected while installation as specified on the Ubuntu website, which didnt. Due to that I had to install without the updates. I tried installing the same Ubuntu on another laptop and the wireless network was easily detected and I was also able to connect to it.

Comment: I edited my answer, 12.04 does not support your device by default, since you have a newer kernel installed I thought it might work but it is not going to. Thanks